# Querying mongo date field with predefined intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

I'm building an app that will allow customers to sign-up with yearly billing. The problem that I'm facing is that the quota associated with accounts is based on monthly periods (yes, even for yearly accounts).

When someone signs-up with yearly billing, in Mongo, I store when his/hers subscription renews (that's essentially now + one year) like so:

```
{
    "renews_at" : ISODate("2020-09-02T20:02:55.813Z")
}
```

I would like to setup an internal cron job that would fire every hour on every day and check which of the yearly accounts should have their quota reset (on a *monthly* basis) as if they would renew on monthly basis within the next hour.

That's the most clear explanation of the problem I can give.

For example, let's take an account from the code above. It renews on the 2020-09-02 at 20:02:55. So a cron job that fires on every second day of month at 20:00:00 should running that account (in order for me to reset its monthly quota).

To make things more clear, cron jobs running at the times below should always return the above account:

```
2019-09-02 at 20:00:00
2019-10-02 at 20:00:00
2019-11-02 at 20:00:00
2019-12-02 at 20:00:00
```

and so on.

In other words, "return all yearly accounts that would renew within the next hour as if they would be billed monthly".

One possible solution to that problem that I have is to always reset the quota on the first day of the month. Than I only need to have a monthly-based cron job that fires on the 1st of each month but that's sub-optimal. If someone signs up in the middle of the month then this should be his/hers billing cycle.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you take a look at [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) on monogodb ? look at `$year`, `$month` and `$dayOfMonth`

Comment: @Tareq how would I use that aggregation is my scenario?